# Evaluation of the XPath expression resulted in an error

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to perform a simple XPath expression on a string (for example, `FHP2019/0156`). My aim is to replace the `/` character with an `_` character.

The XPath expression I've used is: `fn:replace($ctx:ApplicationID , '/', '_')`

But I'm getting the following error:

> Evaluation of the XPath expression fn:replace($ctx:ApplicationID ,
>   '/', '_') resulted in an error

Comment: `get-property(...)` is not a standard XPath function. And `fn:replace` is an XPath-2.0 function which is only valid if your XPath processor supports XPath-2.0 or above.

Comment: Thanks. Is fn:replace($ctx:ApplicationID , '/', '_') a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, replace is a XPATH 2.0 function, you have to enable xpath 2.0 in the esb. Uncomment the "synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true" line inside synapse.properties conf file and restart the server. You may have to change your expression from "**fn:replace($ctx:ApplicationID , '/', '*')***" to "**replace($ctx:ApplicationID , '/', '')**"

Please note that, enabling xpath 2.0 functions might affect other xpath expressions already defined. In that case you may have to find an alternative for fn:replace.